# Xcode 8.1 Not Autocompleting type alias callbacks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It's really weird for Xcode (Version 8.1 (8B62)) to act like this, not helping me to auto complete the callbacks, let me give you a specific example:

See the photo, when I double click or enter in that suggested call back, which is the **SingleRequestCallBack**, Xcode should give me a block. But it's not. Instead Xcode just completing that statement which is **FirebaseSingleRequest.SingleRequestCallBack**, and if you double click on the suggested call back, Xcode would give you a bug report in your editor and making all the codes white.

That happens too in the Firebase library and even in the UIViewController functions (such as **dismiss**). See the second screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Steps I already made:

1. Clean and Clean the Build of the project.
2. Restart Xcode
3. Shut down the machine.

So the question is: How to fix this? What causes this issue?

Comment: Clean the derived data folder.

Comment: Its true, XCode 8.1 has this bug, @Adeel it has nothing to do with cleaning derive data folder.

Comment: Yeah I tried deleting the derived data folder. Issue persists. So do I have to revert my Xcode to 8.0?

Comment: Hahahahaha. I love how people say "Clean the derived data folder" whenever something goes wrong in Xcode. Not making fun of you @Adeel because that's the first thing I do whenever something's not working XD